# Is it possible to get first value for each distinct record found?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to create a query that will give me the first value for each distinct filename? Below is some sample data that I'm working with.

```
        Filename                        Ticket
--------------------------------------|-----------
WMSORD_201302271225_72929031818357.txt| 0802228291          
WMSORD_201302271225_72929031818357.txt| 0802228294          
WMSORD_201302271225_72929031818357.txt| 0802228298          
WMSORD_201302271225_72929031818357.txt| 0802228299          
WMSORD_201302271225_72929031818357.txt| 0802228302          
WMSORD_201302271225_72929031818357.txt| 0802228303          
WMSORD_201302271225_72929031818357.txt| 0802228306          
WMSORD_201303051754_35529747798357.txt| 0802265977          
WMSORD_201303051754_35529747798357.txt| 0802265978          
WMSORD_201303051754_35529747798357.txt| 0802265979          
WMSORD_201303080927_83230090638357.txt| 0802284105          
WMSORD_201303080948_90430092648357.txt| 0802284233          
WMSORD_201303080948_90430092648357.txt| 0802284234          
WMSORD_201303080948_90430092648357.txt| 0802284235          
WMSORD_201303080948_90430092648357.txt| 0802284236          
WMSORD_201303080957_67930093468357.txt| 0802284303          
WMSORD_201303080957_67930093468357.txt| 0802284305          
WMSORD_201303081038_42730097848357.txt| 0802286362          
WMSORD_201303081038_42730097848357.txt| 0802286364          
WMSORD_201303081038_42730097848357.txt| 0802286366          
WMSORD_201303081038_42730097848357.txt| 0802286367
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `MIN()`

```
SELECT  FileName, MIN(Ticket) Ticket
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY FileName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cae89/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║                FILENAME                ║  TICKET   ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ WMSORD_201302271225_72929031818357.txt ║ 802228291 ║
║ WMSORD_201303051754_35529747798357.txt ║ 802265977 ║
║ WMSORD_201303080927_83230090638357.txt ║ 802284105 ║
║ WMSORD_201303080948_90430092648357.txt ║ 802284233 ║
║ WMSORD_201303080957_67930093468357.txt ║ 802284303 ║
║ WMSORD_201303081038_42730097848357.txt ║ 802286362 ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```